# Does React Native navigator.geolocation.watchPosition run in background?

Tags: reactjs, geolocation, react-native

I have the following code and wonder if it runs when the app is in the background for both iOS and Android and also web app:

```
var id = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(success, error, options);
```

Answer (score 1):

It does run when the app is in the background for iOS and Android not for web app, and not when the app is not running.

Answer (score 1):

See this link for a complete guide on how to do geolocation with react-native https://blog.expo.io/a-complete-guide-to-recording-location-data-in-react-native-9ee6e1ef7893.

Basically what it is saying is that you can do geolocation tracking in the background but only if you use native code or a framework that does that, not with the react-native wrappers or expo.

Comment: That article is behind a paywall.

Comment: Yes, because Expo's blog is hosted on medium unfortunately. Too bad.